# Let interaction with new user's posts in Q&A count towards review badge

Tags: feature-request, review, badges

On any SE site, in the First Posts review queue we review new user's posts. As with any queue, we can get the Custodian, Reviewer, and Steward badges for reviewing a certain number of items in this queue.

However, most of the time, especially when using smaller SE sites, I comment, vote on, flag, or vote to close a new user's post before going through the First Posts review queue. I am then unable to review this post in the First Posts review queue because I've already interacted with it.

Given we're fulfilling the purpose of the review queue by interacting with the new user's post on the Q&A, I think interacting with new user's posts on the Q&A should count towards the reviewing badges.

This would help improve the quality of the site in general because users will be further encouraged to upvote, comment, and help new users while on the Q&A portion more than they currently do.